# multi-level (4) Otsu thresholding

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement multi-level Otsu's thresholding, more specifically I need 3 thresholds/4 classes.

I'm aware of 2 similair questions on SO about it: #34856019 and #22706742.
The problem is that I don't get good results: I've read several articles with sample images and thresholds found by that code differ from the ones in these papers.

Let's say I have a picture with 3 circles on the black background, the brightness of the circles differ from very bright to dark:

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QBhv.png)

Am I right to suppose to get as a result 4 classes: black background and 3 more classes according to circles' intensity?

My program gives me these threshold values: **226, 178, 68**

As a result, the third circle is completely invisible - it's in the same class as the background.

Can someone please check these values and/or the source code? Maybe it is possible to check this image using Matlab or somehow else...
By the way, what's the best way to handle divisions by zero, which happen often with zero values in histogram?
The source code:

```
void MultilevelThresholding(cv::Mat& src)
{
    int histogram[256] = { 0 };
    int pixelsCount = src.cols * src.rows;

    for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
        {
            uchar value = src.at<uchar>(y, x);
            histogram[value]++;
        }
    }

    double c = 0;
    double Mt = 0;

    double p[256] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        p[i] = (double) histogram[i] / (double) pixelsCount;
        Mt += i * p[i];
    }

    int optimalTreshold1 = 0;
    int optimalTreshold2 = 0;
    int optimalTreshold3 = 0;

    double maxBetweenVar = 0;

    double w0 = 0;
    double m0 = 0;
    double c0 = 0;
    double p0 = 0;

    double w1 = 0;
    double m1 = 0;
    double c1 = 0;
    double p1 = 0;

    double w2 = 0;
    double m2 = 0;
    double c2 = 0;
    double p2 = 0;
    for (int tr1 = 0; tr1 < 256; tr1++)
    {
        p0 += p[tr1];
        w0 += (tr1 * p[tr1]);
        if (p0 != 0)
        {
            m0 = w0 / p0;
        }

        c0 = p0 * (m0 - Mt) * (m0 - Mt);

        c1 = 0;
        w1 = 0;
        m1 = 0;
        p1 = 0;
        for (int tr2 = tr1 + 1; tr2 < 256; tr2++)
        {

            p1 += p[tr2];
            w1 += (tr2 * p[tr2]);
            if (p1 != 0)
            {
                m1 = w1 / p1;
            }

            c1 = p1 * (m1 - Mt) * (m1 - Mt);


            c2 = 0;
            w2 = 0;
            m2 = 0;
            p2 = 0;
            for (int tr3 = tr2 + 1; tr3 < 256; tr3++)
            {

                p2 += p[tr3];
                w2 += (tr3 * p[tr3]);
                if (p2 != 0)
                {
                    m2 = w2 / p2;
                }

                c2 = p2 * (m2 - Mt) * (m2 - Mt);

                c = c0 + c1 + c2;

                if (maxBetweenVar < c)
                {
                    maxBetweenVar = c;
                    optimalTreshold1 = tr1;
                    optimalTreshold2 = tr2;
                    optimalTreshold3 = tr3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try to add a big median filter to remove the fading effect at the edges? Did you try k-means clustering (4 cluster) instead of otsu?

Comment: yes, I can add any filter I want, but this is just an example - the question is about Otsu and its threshold values. Do you think it gets them right?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like your code only assumes 3 thresholds (optimalThreshold1-3) instead of 4?

Comment: yes, 3 thresholds give us 4 classes, the same way as 1 threshold in a binary thresholding gives us (n+1) = 2 classes - black and white.

Comment: yes, you are obviously right. Did you try to draw the grayscale histogram?

Comment: I definitely can draw it, but I don't think I can find 3 threshold values just looking at it, so I'm hoping somebody will tell me what are the real values for this particular image or maybe will point me at mistakes in the code.

Comment: 1 thing i recognized is that your code detects the top end of the threshold value. For example having 4 intensities in the image: 0, 30, 150, 200, it will detect the thresholds 30, 150, 200 exactly "correctly", but the original 2-class otsu would find threshold 127 instead of 255 if the image only has intensities 0 and 255.

Comment: thank you! Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: no, do you have a link or name of a paper describing the method?

Comment: I just adapted the original method to 3 threshold values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method

Comment: Actually there's a problem: somehow I didn't notice that a have only 3 classes in my code: c0, c1 and c2, but obviously there should be 4...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put in the 4th class everything that left from previous 3: double p3 = 1 - (p0 + p1 + p2);
    double w3 = Mt - (w0 + w1 + w2);
    double m3 = w3 / p3;
    double c3 = p3 * (m3 - Mt) * (m3 - Mt);

    double c = c0 + c1 + c2 + c3;

Comment: I think the question is closed. Thank you Micka, can I somehow upvote your comments?

Comment: no, but that's no problem =)

Comment: If you are certain that your question is answered, remember to accept the (even if it's your own) answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've figured it out. The final source code for 4 classes (3 thresholds) Otsu thresholding:

```
// cv::Mat& src - source image's matrix
    int histogram[256] = { 0 };
    int pixelsCount = src.cols * src.rows;

    for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
        {
            uchar value = src.at<uchar>(y, x);
            histogram[value]++;
        }
    }

    double c = 0;
    double Mt = 0;

    double p[256] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        p[i] = (double) histogram[i] / (double) pixelsCount;
        Mt += i * p[i];
    }

    int optimalTreshold1 = 0;
    int optimalTreshold2 = 0;
    int optimalTreshold3 = 0;

    double maxBetweenVar = 0;

    double w0 = 0;
    double m0 = 0;
    double c0 = 0;
    double p0 = 0;

    double w1 = 0;
    double m1 = 0;
    double c1 = 0;
    double p1 = 0;

    double w2 = 0;
    double m2 = 0;
    double c2 = 0;
    double p2 = 0;
    for (int tr1 = 0; tr1 < 256; tr1++)
    {
        p0 += p[tr1];
        w0 += (tr1 * p[tr1]);
        if (p0 != 0)
        {
            m0 = w0 / p0;
        }

        c0 = p0 * (m0 - Mt) * (m0 - Mt);

        c1 = 0;
        w1 = 0;
        m1 = 0;
        p1 = 0;
        for (int tr2 = tr1 + 1; tr2 < 256; tr2++)
        {

            p1 += p[tr2];
            w1 += (tr2 * p[tr2]);
            if (p1 != 0)
            {
                m1 = w1 / p1;
            }

            c1 = p1 * (m1 - Mt) * (m1 - Mt);


            c2 = 0;
            w2 = 0;
            m2 = 0;
            p2 = 0;
            for (int tr3 = tr2 + 1; tr3 < 256; tr3++)
            {

                p2 += p[tr3];
                w2 += (tr3 * p[tr3]);
                if (p2 != 0)
                {
                    m2 = w2 / p2;
                }

                c2 = p2 * (m2 - Mt) * (m2 - Mt);

                double p3 = 1 - (p0 + p1 + p2);
                double w3 = Mt - (w0 + w1 + w2);
                double m3 = w3 / p3;
                double c3 = p3 * (m3 - Mt) * (m3 - Mt);

                double c = c0 + c1 + c2 + c3;

                if (maxBetweenVar < c)
                {
                    maxBetweenVar = c;
                    optimalTreshold1 = tr1;
                    optimalTreshold2 = tr2;
                    optimalTreshold3 = tr3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VglUJ.png)

[image]

[Result: 3 thresholds / 4 classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi2eg.png)

[image]
threshold values: **179, 92, 25**

Comment: What was worng? can you elaborate more?