# Opencv 2 multi-threshold Otsu method

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

I know how to call binary Otsu method for a greyscale image:

`threshold(image, opencv_otsu_result, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);`

But I don't understand how to use this function if I want divide my image into 3, 4,... colors. I am trying to find some function like:

`threshold(image, result, SOME_FLAGS, number_of_colors);`

Comment: There's no OpenCV function to do this. However, you can find examples for [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34856019/5008845) and [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35056760/5008845) levels

Comment: Or you can go through Matlab [multithresh](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/multithresh.html) code and port to OpenCV

Comment: @Miki Actually I implemented my own multi-threshold Otsu and I'd like to compare it with opencv realization. Thank You

Comment: @Miki Could you write it as an answer for my question so I will mark it as a solution :)